# STRIPE: How Do I get this checkout form to work

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've been having a bunch of trouble with getting Stripe to work for me and have googled a bunch of examples but cant seem to get it to make charges.

I'm using Stripes, simple checkout form, and it is definitely generating a stripe token because I can see it in the stripe logs. I then have the form execute charge.php which receives the stripe token as a POST variable and this is def working because I can echo the token.

The problem is that it then does nothing and doesn't throw any error nor charge the card.

The code is as follows:
Checkout page:

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="test key"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

The Actual PHP script which charges: charge.php

```
<?php

require('Absolute Link to site /lib/Stripe.php');
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
Stripe::setApiKey("test key");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
        "currency" => "aud",
        "card" => $token,
        "description" => "VIP Basic"
    ));
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    // The card has been declined
}

?>
```

I emailed stripe support and they say the `charge.php` code works on their end and to check whether the libs are being called correctly. There aren't any warnings and nothing in the error_log.

Does anyone have any ideas? It should be the simplest thing in the world and i'm tearing my hair out over it and just cant see it.

Comment: Have you tried using someting like Fiddler or Wireshark on your server to see if the library is actually making the REST request to Stripe's servers? Perhaps its not even attempting it due to some strange configuration issue.

Comment: Double check that Absolute Link to site /lib/Stripe.php is correct, if charge is in the same folder as lib it should be ./lib/Stripe.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be with the card not accepting aud, you should try visa or mastercard. If you are seeing the generated token in the dashboard try the below ajax method. include stripe.js and jquery.

```
 <input type="text" id="card_number">
 <input type="text" id="cvc">
 <input type="text" id="ex_month">
 <input type="text" id="ex_year">
 <button id="paynow">Pay Now</button>   

$('#paynow').click(function(){
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_Bwg5tfiOULnNK8DvS60zJ2Sm');
    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $("#card_number").val(),
      cvc: $("#cvc").val(),
      exp_month: $("#ex_month")val(),
      exp_year: $("#ex_year").val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
function stripeResponseHandler(status, error){
  if(response.error){
      alert(response.error.message);
  }
  else {
   $.ajax({
     url: 'charge.php',
     type:'POST',
     data:{token:response.id},
     cache:false,
     success: function(data){
          alert(data);
     }
   });
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct and should work, so the issue is most likely that the card is being declined, but you aren't handling the error. Add some code to this part:

```
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
    // The card has been declined
}
```

Echo out the error, etc, and you'll probably discover the problem.